# Error while installing texlive which took almost two hours

Tags: installing, texlive-2020

I was installing texlive, but at the end of the installation, it showed:
Installation failed.

```
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl-windows.bat --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]
or
  install-tl-advanced.bat --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]
C:/Users/Prashanta/AppData/Local/Temp/nsnD3AF.tmp/install-tl-20200815/install-tl: Writing log in current directory: C:/Users/PRASHA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/nsnD3AF.tmp/install-tl.log
```

It took almost two hours showed the above lines. Can you kindly help so that I can install properly waithut faliure. My system is windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: Are you installing as the administrator?  Do you have administration privileges?

Comment: you haven't showed the error, just the message to try restarting. what does `install-tl.log` say?

Comment: I have texted what came at the end of the installation. I did not found some other thing like what you are saying.

Comment: The last line you quoted mentions a logfile. If it is still there, it might contain better information.